# Azure AD/Token/Certificates/SQL - I'm lost

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I started a company 3 months ago and there is no software (CRM+other business tasks) that meets my needs.  Reluctantly I decided to write my own 2 months ago and it is now 80% complete!  I've been pointed here to Stack Overflow throughout my journey many times and you guys have been a great help -- first and foremost thank you!  I've been able to stay quiet until now...

The problem:
I have connection strings all over the place with SQL Authentication username/password exposed.  My business partner is across the country so I need to give him access and open a port etc.  I've made the move to Microsoft Azure (all setup with a VPN gateway, VM's are running and linked with Azure AD) to lockdown the environment a bit.  I'd like to take full advantage of what it offers and use Active Directory for authentication on login (MFA) and then use the token in my query strings removing the need for a hard coded connection string with username/passwords...

I've done a lot of research and it seems I can accomplish what I want but I can't quite figure it out.

App is written in VB.net and most Microsoft docs on the topic are in C#, requiring edits to the app.xaml.cs file which doesn't exist in vb.net, and even if I got around that piece i'm not sure how to configure the sql connection strings to use the token.

Once I get this out of the way I can get back to finishing the software so I can get on the phone and help us take off before the money runs out!  Your help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT :
I'm going this route because from what I've found, I can't use Authentication = Active Directory Integrated in my sql string because my AD is not federated (no on-premise ADFS), Active Directory Password still requires the sql admin setup in Azure to be in the sql string.  I looked at key vaults which while doing research led me to registering my app which seems to be exactly what I want and where my questions is derived.  Microsoft provides a great example downloadable project but again its in C#...If there is a recommendation on a different option i'm all ears...

EDIT 9/3/19 -- A lot of circling and research...I need to convert this code from c# to vb.net.  More information on what the below is and how it is broken down from its creator : https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/configuring-aad-authentication-to-azure-sql-databases

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret, string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
    var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret); << CAN I MAKE THESE (ClientId, ClientSecret) TIED TO TEXTBOXES FOR USERNAME/PASSWORD ON MY APPLICATION?
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not get token");
    }

    return result.AccessToken; <<WHAT DOES RETURN DO HERE?
}

AND

public async Task<SqlConnection> GetSqlConnectionAsync(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string dbServer, string dbName)
{
    var authority = string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantId);
    var resource = "https://database.windows.net/";
    var scope = "";
    var token = await GetTokenAsync(clientId, clientSecret, authority, resource, scope);

    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder["Data Source"] = $"{dbServer}.database.windows.net";
    builder["Initial Catalog"] = dbName;
    builder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;
    builder["Persist Security Info"] = false;
    builder["TrustServerCertificate"] = false;
    builder["Encrypt"] = true;
    builder["MultipleActiveResultSets"] = false;

    var con = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
    con.AccessToken = token;
    return con;
}
```

Comment: So are you looking for a way to use Azure key vault to store your SQL connection string  in VB?

Comment: if that's the best/most secure option...then yes.  Main goal is to remove username/password from sql connection strings.  If I can tie to it azure active directory as well for further authentication/security/tracking that would be excellent and I would prefer that method.

Comment: Here is the link to the c# sample from Microsoft that has you login via credentials on your azure active directory and creates/gets the token.  I want exactly that in VB.net and then use that token in my sql connection string.  Is this a good/best way of doing it and can anyone help me accomplish what is happening in that sample project in vb.net rather than c#?  I tried translating both through a converter and my own limited knowledge but there are namespaces and other things happening that are a bit outside of my capabilities.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/

Comment: Unfortunately, On-premise SQL Server only supports Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication. Windows authentication depends on Kerberos (or NTLM), which needs an Active Directory domain to authenticate the user in. Azure Active Directory does not handle Kerberos tokens. So you cant use tokens from Azure AD to connect to your SQL server.
If you just want not t leak your sql server auth info (username/password) , through sql server connection string , using Azure key vault will be a proper choice . May I know the details about where the connection string will be used ?

Comment: Right now connection string is on every form which I hate...I planned on getting back to that towards the end and cleaning it up when I got back to the security piece...and here I am haha.  I know I should have it in my app.config but I didn't spend much time looking at the encryption piece for that...maybe you can elaborate or should I create a new thread for that?  Also on the original topic...I found this and have been playing with it for the past couple hours...will this not work for what I want?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/02/09/token-based-authentication-support-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-ad-auth/

Comment: if you download the zip there is a sample project that authenticates against azure AD grants a token against a certificate you create/upload to azure/through powershell.  Its not letting me connect through the database which im trying to sort out now but i am getting the token.  The code looks like it is completing the sql connection string using the token right?  no username/password?  Again though its in csharp but much much less complicated than the Microsoft graph one i mentioned above...

Comment: When I say "not letting me connect to the database" I'm getting the anonymous login message everyone was posting about in the link...im fairly certain that is because I am not testing it on my VM in azure which I am logged into with credentials in the AD...i'm going to try it now but if that works...this should be the answer and from a security perspective it is working correctly since it wouldn't work on my pc off the virtual network even though I happened to have the certificate...lets see!

Comment: I am afraid yes, you can not use Azure AD tokens to connect to SQL server . If you your sql server connection string is configed in a config file such as app.config and you want to hide it, using Azure key vault is the best way for you . If you use Azure PaaS service to host your app , the process that you getting connection string from key vault will be seamless .For instance , if your app is a web app, you can host it on Azure app service and integrate with key vault directly , there is no code need to be implemented , just some configs on Azure platform

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: Still getting the anonymous login error on the azure vm...fearing you may be right but still going to crack at it and will report back.  Hard headed as usual, I attempted to email the email address provided on the link I provided...its no longer active and comments are disabled on the post...I guess that's not a good sign.  My Microsoft salesrep was copied so lets see if he can poke around for me...hes top-notch.  Will post the bottom line here soon.  Appreciate your help Stanley.

Comment: Welcome Carmine, I am waiting for the update here too

Comment: Poking around a bit more on this and I noticed the poster made mention of an updated version but there was no link...I found it..https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2017/04/25/certificate-based-authentication-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-active-directory-with-recent-azure-rm-powershell-version/

Comment: So lets say what I want doesn't exist...any reason why we couldn't make a combination of both certificate and login/authentication through Active Directory Password?  In other words...active directory password on its own requires a username/password setup as the AAD admin and then creates a user in sql based on that login...haven't done it in practice but research a good bit about it and that is what I understand.  So is there any reason I couldn't authenticate against aad/cert tied to my application and local machine(vm) and then use aad password in code/using the key vault method you mention

Comment: literally this : https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/configuring-aad-authentication-to-azure-sql-databases

Comment: Yes, you can use Azure AD access token to connect to your Azure SQL DB, however , if you use SQL server that hosted on Azure VMs ,as far as I know, it not works .

Comment: Excellent news!  Sorry for not being clear, I am using the VM's as workstations only, the SQL DB is an Azure SQL DB...not hosted on a VM...I am having my users connect through a VPN to the virtual network and then to the VM to lockdown that piece.  Can you help me come up with some vb.net code to implement this?  I'm trying to work with the code on the last link I posted but without understanding the syntax in c# this could take a while...

Comment: i guess ill post the code above and edit my original post...i'm not sure of best way to do it as its my first go around posting on here...

Comment: So you want to know how to get this access token in VB ?

Comment: Yes, I want to point my login button when a user first opens the application to getting the token, authenticating the username/password they enter via textbox OR PREFERABLY a Microsoft login screen would appear linked to my tenant id so they would have to perform MFA authentication everytime they login and then that code would modify the sql connection string with the token.

Comment: You have two levels of authentication here: 1. The user logging into your app; 2. The app authenticating to the database. (1) can be MFA AAD etc., (2) can just be SQL authentication. They don't have to be the same. You really generated some extra work for yourself choosing VB as your programming language!

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that you want to use Azure AD access token to connect to Azure SQL DB. Based on the docs you provided and my own research , for now, we can use Azure AD service principle to get access token to connect to Azure SQL only.

I believe you have did some research on it already and find the codes to implement it using C# SDK. However there is no VB.net code sample to do it which confused you .

Honestly , I am not so familiar with VB.net , but I still implemented a demo to do that for you , pls refer to the code below :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim tenant = ""
        Dim client_id = ""
        Dim username = ""
        Dim password = ""
        Dim client_secret = ""
        Dim sqlserverName = ""
        Dim dbname = ""

        Dim dbConn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection

        dbConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + sqlserverName + ".database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=" + dbname + ";Connect Timeout=30"
        dbConn.AccessToken = getAccessToken(tenant, client_id, client_secret, username, password)

        Console.WriteLine("User: " + username)

        Console.WriteLine("access token value:" + dbConn.AccessToken)


        dbConn.Open()

        Dim sqlQuery = "select @@version"

        Dim Result = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dbConn).ExecuteScalar()

        Console.WriteLine("query result from Azure SQL : " + Result.ToString)
        Console.ReadKey()


    End Sub

    Function getAccessToken(tenant, client_id, client_secret, username, password) As String
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant + "/oauth2/token")
        request.Method = "POST"
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"


        Dim requestBody =
        "grant_type=client_credentials" +
        "&client_id=" + client_id +
        "&client_secret=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(client_secret) +
        "&username=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(username) +
        "&password=" + WebUtility.UrlDecode(password) +
        "&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fdatabase.windows.net%2F"

        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(requestBody)

        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
        Dim postreqstream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()

        Dim result = request.GetResponseAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()

        Dim result_str = New StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd

        Dim tokenResp As TokenResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of TokenResponse)(result_str)

        Return tokenResp.access_token

    End Function


    Public Class TokenResponse
        Public Property token_type As String
        Public Property expires_in As String
        Public Property ext_expires_in As String
        Public Property expires_on As String
        Public Property not_before As String
        Public Property resource As String
        Public Property access_token As String
    End Class

End Module
```

Pls refer to the steps below to create associated Azure AD apps and fill all params to run it :

1. Creating a Azure AD app in your tenant ,type its name and click register directly, in my case , the app name is **DBadmin**: 
   [image]
2. Note its **application ID** : 
   [image]
3. Creating a client secret for this app and note the secret :
   [image]
4. Adding Azure SQL user login permission to this app :
   [image]
   [image]
   Grant permission as an admin:
   [image]
5. Go to "Groups" blade ,create an Azure AD group , adding the app we just created at same time :
   [image]
6. Go to the Azure SQL server that you want to access , and adding the group we just created in to Azure AD admin  of SQL server :
   [image]
   [image]

Remember to click save after adding .

Ok, we have done all configs here , just modify the params in code to try to connect to your Azure SQL .

Code result : 
[image]

Hope it helps . Anyway If you just want to hide connection string in your config file.Key vault should be the best choice for you .

Comment: Hi , good news , I have digged out that how to use user access token to access Azure SQL server , codes and steps have been updated . Enjoy it ! For more queries about MFA , that will involve more Azure AD related things ,on my opinion , we should do that step by step ,at least make sure we are on the correct way . So , pls check it first that if this solution meet your requirement : )

Comment: Hi Stanley, thanks so much for the detailed explanation and help -- it is much appreciated.  I've been working with Microsoft on the issue...I think the answer was in front of us all along but I didn't realize it could/would work.  Simple question -- why not create a vm as a server and federate it to azure?  So I did that -- and it is a great option so that I have some additional user control over what azure ad provides.  I was also able to save a bunch of money by getting rid of azure ad domain services (managed)...but im still having an issue using the connection string with

Comment: Authentication = Active Directory Integrated when running my application on a system that is signed in through active directory.  In the azure portal it is showing that the domain is federated.  I get "one or more errors occurred"  -- should I change my code to try/catch to see what the actual issue is?  Also now that ive finally got the federation working when trying to login (AD Password) to the azure sql database im getting an error "The Function is unfamiliar with the certificate authority that generated the server's certificate" certificate was self signed...

Comment: Lastly, I did select options>trust the server's certificate and this still happens.

Comment: Update : Progress!! the error is AdalException :  could not discover endpoint for integrate windows authentication so I researched how to fix that, enabled the windowstransport endpoint restarted the server and still getting the same error?

Comment: Its the SPN on the service account...I remember seeing a warning when I first set it up but thought if it didn't prevent me from proceeding I could get away with it...nope!  that's what is preventing the discovery of the endpoint because the endpoint service isn't starting...removing ad fs and reinstalling -- hopefully don't need to wipe and start clean...if I do whatever at this point...very very close to putting this chapter to bed!

Comment: Hi , @Carmine seems your queries are all around on-prem AD , however I am skilled at Azure AD only... If your solution is about Azure AD pls feel free to let me know. Sorry for that

Comment: no problem at all Stanley.  I'm going to go back and visit all of the above as soon as I get this thing running...thank you so much for your time and effort -- this journey has been hugely different going in mostly blind but really a lot of fun and huge amounts of info!

Comment: Sure , @Carmine if my code works for you , pls mark my answer : )  Thanks !