# Getting MsalClientException while requesting token from EWS.AccessAsUser.All using delegate permission

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have followed all the step mentioned in this answer given by @Robert Muehsig and added the code in .net framework console app after running I am getting below error,

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: 'There was an error parsing WS-Trust response from the endpoint. This may occur if there is an issue with your ADFS configuration. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa-troubleshooting for more details. Error Message: returned error: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized. '

**code part**

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "ClientId",
                TenantId = "TenantId"
            };

            var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "Password")
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);

            var cred = new NetworkCredential("Username", securePassword);

            var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" }, cred.UserName, cred.SecurePassword).ExecuteAsync();
```

During registration I have set "Treat application as public client" true.

From postman I able to get token but if add it during debug point it will throw 401 error.

Comment: @8949365 could you please tell me how it worked for you? Any changes we need make during app registration.

Comment: Whether it need to be go via proxy network?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask].   This is not a user forum like you think it is.    Ask for clarification on the other question you seem to have found they are not going to see this here.

Answer (score 0):

- It looks like either the username or  password passed in the
  credentials are incorrect.
- Also use current or latest version of `dot net` to clear the issues
  regarding compatibility
- As you are getting token, after decoding it check the audience is
  valid, and see if it is either clientId or appId uri.
  If not  try to change the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to 2 if it is
  null or to 1 or null if it is 2.

[image]

And make sure the scope `https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All` that  is given in code is also given in azure ad portal and ***`granted admin consent`*** from admin and users if set to consent by them .

Comment: This issue resolved by giving "full_acces_as_app" application permission. Thanks @kavya

Comment: How to get token in Vb.net?

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747706/azure-ad-token-certificates-sql-im-lost/57781545#57781545) and [vb.net use msal](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/12/vb-net-use-msal-net-in-a-console-application-to-authenticate-to-azure/) if it gives an idea.